# Quarter circle tag cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tag-cloud

What would be the best way of building a tag cloud in the shape of a quarter circle, any pointers to good resources will be helpful, rest assured I've already searched google for this.

Comment: Sorry but "a tag cloud in the shape of a quarter circle" is really not much to run with. Can you please provide a diagram or such and what your thoughts and ideas are, and what you have tried, apart from googling.

Comment: Tag clouds are just divs. I imagine he wants his div in the shape of a quarter circle (Pie piece) and his tag content to obey the boundaries of the container.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started ;)

HTML:

```
    <div id="tag_cloud">
        <div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:131px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:92px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:71px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:51px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:38px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:26px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:17px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:13px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:10px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:7px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:5px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:4px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:2px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:left;clear:left;height:15px;width:0px"></div><div style="float:right;clear:right;height:15px;width:0px"></div>

    <!-- TAGS GO HERE -->
    blue, d70, ddlatt, deborahlattimore, dlattimore, dragonfly, drops, eau, eye, f18, f28d, fernandinabeach, flickr, florida, fly, fun, fungyuenbutterflyreserve, fv10, gato, germany, harbor, india, interestingness, keurboomstrand, lattimore, leaf, leaves, macro, may, nightphotography, nikon300mmf28vr, nikon55mmmacro, nikonvr, oscarl\u00F3pez, panorama, ph213, pink, religion, ring, sf, southafrica, spring, storm, street, tahoe, telephoto, thereseflanagancom, topv444, urban, wow
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tag_cloud {
    background-color:pink;
    border-top-left-radius:200px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:200px;
    height:140px;
    width:140px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:60px;
    padding-left:60px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/RN5zV/3/

Also a good resource for this idea: http://www.csstextwrap.com